# Eratosthenes Sieve - finding the order of crossing numbers out

Tags: python, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

first off let. me say this is not a homework:)
in Eratosthenes Sieve, from 1 to a given number k, I want to find and return the order of crossing out a given number n without using list, tuple, set and dictionary (or such data structures)

I came up with the code below which will show me the total composite numbers from 2 to k. But I cannot come up with the general idea of my main problem.

```
k = int (input())
n = int (input())
order = 0 
for i in range(2,n+1):
   for j in range(2,i): 
     if i%j ==0: 
         order += 1  
         break
print (order)
```

as an example, if you notice this code for numbers 1-10, you will see that 10 is crossed out after 9. while in reality this is not true.
I would be so thankful if you help me fix this code as I am overthinking on it for 7 weeks already :(

Comment: Could you reformat your code?

Comment: You never use `k` in this code.  And since you aren't remembering the numbers you crossed out, you'll get them multiple times.  You'll get 16 once when `i` is 2, once when `i` is 4, and once when `i` is 8.  Remember that you don't have to loop up to `i` to learn whether a number is prime.  You can stop at `sqrt(i)`.

Comment: What you show is not the Sieve of Eratosthenes, so your first goal might be to look that up somewhere (in your textbook, or class notes, or on the internet if all else fails) and implement that. Using the right algorithm will make it easier to understand what is meant by "crossing out" in this assignment.

Comment: Well, yes; if the only way that you change `order` is `order+=1`, then it will only ever increase once at a time; and if you only ever print it once at the end, then you will only see its final value. It's not clear how you intend for the code to work; in particular, it isn't clear what the variables `i` and `j` are intended to represent. Try to think clearly about your intended logic, and explain it, step by step, in complete English sentences.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're problem description says.  We keep a set of the composite numbers we've already crossed out.  For each number in the range, if it's not a known composite, then we "cross out" all the multiples of that number that aren't already in the `comps` set.  We print the composites as we cross them out.

```
k = int(input())
n = int(input())
comps = set()
order = 0 
for i in range(2,n+1):
    if i in comps:
        continue
    for j in range(i+i,n,i):
        if j not in comps:
            comps.add(j)
            print(j)
            if j == k:
                order = len(comps)
print()
print(order)
```

Comment: well as I mentioned I don't want to use data structures like sets, lists and etc..
you think there is a solution without sets, lists and etc? (I found such solution using lists but I prefer not using data structures when it is possible to solve without them. I saw in youtube that solving problems with preliminary concepts will help a lot to learn programming and that is why I am challenging over these stuff)

Comment: @Michael: The sieve of Eratosthenes is all about using space (that is, a data structure) to improve on the time-performance of finding primes. If you aren't going to use any data structure, your code will be less efficient that one that does, and you won't be able to mark off the composites in the order the sieve does, since you won't be finding composites the way a sieve does at all. Trial division (which is what your code in the question does) is a completely different algorithm.

Comment: Right.  The point of the sieve is to create a sieve (data structure) and poke holes in it.  There are lots of other ways of computing primes, but they aren't sieves.

Comment: what are those ways? I only could find this way and this code. But any code or way to do without lists or data structures?

Comment: A simple iterative approach works, but is slow.  It's better to keep a list of the primes you have found so far, because those are the only factors you need to check.  The fact is, no one really searches for primes like this.  It's pointless.  It's a solved problem.  People do search for very large primes for cryptography purposes, but those use different techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The Sieve of Eratosthenes crosses out numbers starting with multiples of 2 from 4 (=2^2), then multiples of 3 from 9 (=3^2) and so on through the prime numbers.  You can use what you have found so far to determine the next prime to use.

That gives the crossing-out order as: 4, 6, 8, 10, ... 9, 12, 15, 18, ... 25, 30, 35, 40, ... 49, 56, 63, 70, ... 121, 132, 143, ...